# Google Maps API Convert points (stars) to circles with a radius of 1000 feet

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to convert the stars in the below example to circles that have a radius of 1000 feet. Can anyone assist?

Similar to this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps API</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places,visualization"></script>
    <script>
var map;
var infoWindow;
var service;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.7643389,-104.8551114),
    zoom: 11,
    styles: [
      {
        stylers: [
          { visibility: 'simplified' }
        ]
      },
      {
        elementType: 'labels',
        stylers: [
          { visibility: 'on' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  });

  infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);
}

function performSearch() {
  var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    keyword: 'school'
  };
  service.radarSearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    alert(status);
    return;
  }
  for (var i = 0, result; result = results[i]; i++) {
    createMarker(result);
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location,
    icon: {
      // Star
      path: 'M 0,-24 6,-7 24,-7 10,4 15,21 0,11 -15,21 -10,4 -24,-7 -6,-7 z',
      fillColor: '#ffff00',
      fillOpacity: 1,
      scale: 1/4,
      strokeColor: '#bd8d2c',
      strokeWeight: 1
    }
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.setContent(result.name);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1000ft are 304.8 meters, draw a google.maps.Circle with this `radius` and use the given position as `center`.

To open the infowindow set the position & map-properties (instead of calling the open-method)

```
function createMarker(place) {
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: place.geometry.location,
    radius:304.8
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'click', function() {
    service.getDetails(place, function(result, status) {
      if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        alert(status);
        return;
      }
      infoWindow.setOptions({
                             content:result.name,
                             map:circle.getMap(),
                             position:circle.getCenter()
                            });

    });
  });
}
```